# Split variable-value in a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using Javascript regex functions to split expressions like:

```
var1=32
var2<var4
var1!=var3
```

I'm using this regex:

```
/^(.*)([=|!=|<|>])(.*)$/ig
```

It works pretty well except with the != (different) operator. What's the problem?

Comment: `[]` denotes a character class, meaning this part of your expression is essentially the same as  `[=|!<>]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you are using a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) instead of an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). The expression `[=|!=|<|>]` is equivalent to `[<>=!|]`. Remove the `[` and `]` to get what you want.

```
/^(.*?)(!=|=|<|>)(.*)$/ig
```

I've also changed the first (.*) to be non-greedy so that it doesn't consume the `!` in `!=`. If you know that the left and right expressions will always contain (for example) only alphanumeric characters only, it would be better to specify that instead of matching with the dot.